# how to paginate in cakephp when result comes from several join conditions

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination

I have a problem in cakephp pagination.Before i came deep i would like to display some code that i do in my controller

```
$this->paginate = array(
 'joins' => array(
                array(
                        'table' => 'job_posting_lists',

                        'conditions'=> array('job_posting_lists.firm_id')),
                        array(
                        'table' => 'firmsdetails',
                        'alias' => 'st',
                        'conditions'=> array('st.id')),
                ),               
            'conditions' =>array('job_posting_lists.select_industry'=>$id,'job_posting_lists.verify'=>1),
            'fields' => array('job_posting_lists.*','st.*'),
            'limit' => 3,

            'contain' => array('job_posting_lists'));

        $ListjobBycategories = $this->paginate(); 
        echo "<pre>";print_r($ListjobBycategories); die;
        $this->set('jobbycat',$ListjobBycategories);
```

the result come in ListjobBycategories correct but it returns more data about 1230 and in my job_posting_datas only 5 rows the next page return same result what i do

Comment: I want to paginate $ListjobBycategories data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, make appropriate changes as per your code,

```
$this->paginate = array(
     'joins' => array(
          array(
            'table' => 'tbl1',
            'alias' => 'alias1',
            'conditions'=> array('')
          ),array(
            'table' => 'tbl2',
            'alias' => 'alias2',
            'conditions'=> array('')
          ),array(
            'table' => 'tbl3',
            'alias' => 'alias3',
            'type' => 'left',
            'conditions'=> array('')
          ),
        ),               
                'conditions' => $displayConditions, // Your query conditions
                'fields' => $this->displayFields, // Your field set which you want to retrieve from tables
                'limit' => $show_page,// number of records you wish to retrieve in each page
                'group' => '', // field by which wish to grouping your data set
                'contain' => array(''),//It will contain name of all the Models which are in Join
            );

            $ListjobBycategories = $this->paginate(); // Call pagination function, it will retrieve all records
```

Let me know if any query.

Comment: in condition whose condition i give either join condition or main conditions

Comment: Condition will contain 'Main conditions', for joins you need to add another element 'joins' and add your join conditions there.

Comment: Please check my edited answer now. i think it will helps you better

Comment: 'table' =>'firmsdetails','job_posting_lists', give error

Comment: thanks it works..can you please give me code for view pagination how to show numbers.

Comment: Why it sends repeated data,for example my table contain 1 row but in limit i give 3 and it returns 1 row repeated data.

Comment: Hi, You may need to use **distinct** or **group by** to restrict duplicate data in result set